# Did I ruin my wok?

Tags: temperature, oil, seasoning, wok

I jist got my new wok (I have never used one before), and I wanted to try it out. The package said that it was already seasoned, but I tried to season it nevertheless. Well, I washed the wok first and then put oil in it and turned up the heat to high (induction stove). The oil began to smoke, and the smoke intensity increased. After a while, I decided it was too much smoke and cancelled the process. i was left with a wok, that had burnt oil in it. Idk if is poisonous or not. [image: Current state]

Answer (score 0):

Never eat burnt oil.

A very thin residue of burnt oil is basically your seasoning.

Remove what you can with synthetic scrubber/bamboo wok scrubber with plenty of soap.

Continue the process.
This time applying thin layer of oil with a papertowel.

https://youtu.be/-7zxhd2v-DY